# Online interface for Python GUI examples

Tags: python

Is there any online interface where I can execute my Python GUI scripts? Consider this script for an example:

```
from tkinter import * 
window = Tk()
window.title("Title window")
lbl = Label(window, text="Hello")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

In most of the online interfaces, it gets stuck at second line itself.

Comment: What does online interface mean?  I see the answer below where browser is inferred.

Comment: @Hogstrom: I expect a public web app, like JS Fiddle or SQL Fiddle, which contains a Python runner.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've posted uses Tk which is a desktop GUI toolkit. To run this requires an active window manager, which is not available when running within the browser. This also applies to other desktop toolkits, such as Qt, wx.

There *are* some code-tutoring services that provide custom toolkits which work in the browser from within their shell.

However, if you plan to distribute your code, you're better off either

a. developing the code offline and learning to build native desktop applications, or
b. developing UIs using Javascript in the browser, and building your API in Python

Comment: UIs using HTML in the browser, you mean?

Comment: @cricket_007 yep. You would build the UI using a HTML templates + a JS framework (Angular, React.. etc.) then use Python to serve the data. Whether that makes sense depends on what you're trying to do though.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to develop your GUI with GTK+ and some online code platform would enable it, this could be doable with GTK+' [Broadway backend](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html). But that's a lot of hypothetical already.

I am not even sure why they added that back-end in GTK+ in the first place (play with or debug CSS based UI styling ?). But honestly, I do not know any real world use case for Broadway, though I would be curious to learn about any.

I do not if any other GUI Toolkit (*e.g.* Qt) developed any similar feature.